# Is there any possible way to resize an PNG image in SDL2?

Tags: c++, windows, sdl, sdl-2

I am using `SDL2` and `SDL_image.h`. My current attempt was trying to fit the .PNG image in a `SDL_Rect` which only hid my image in the rectangle's area and thus did not work. I was following [this tutorial](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/06_extension_libraries_and_loading_other_image_formats/index2.php) to load the .PNG image. I'm looking to make the image stretch to the same size of the screen which is 640x480. This was my attempt:

```C++
...
SDL_Rect surfWindRectBC;
SDL_Rect surfWindRectCI;

SDL_Surface * screenSurf = NULL;
SDL_Surface* current = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SDL_Surface * menu = IMG_Load(std::string(".\\sprites\\menu\\background.png").c_str()); 
...
```

```C++
...
int main() {
    surfWindRectBC.w = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    surfWindRectBC.h = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    surfWindRectCI.w = 32;
    surfWindRectCI.h = 32;
...
```

```C++
...
screenSurf = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
current = SDL_ConvertSurface(menu, screenSurf->format,0);
SDL_FreeSurface(menu);
...
```

```C++
...
while (game) {
                SDL_Event event;
                Uint8 input = 0;
                
                while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {...}
                SDL_BlitSurface(current, &surfWindRectBC, screenSurf, &surfWindRectCI);
                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            }
...
```

Comment: Looking at documentation maybe you should try using SDL_BlitScaled instead od SDL_BlitSurface

Comment: YES! It worked, thank you very much. Also just one question, why did you comment? I could mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: `std::string(".\\sprites\\menu\\background.png").c_str()` why such a redundant thing?

Comment: in fact you may invoke UB by doing this `SDL_Surface * menu = IMG_Load(std::string(".\\sprites\\menu\\background.png").c_str());` because the lifetime of the temporary `std::string` ends at the end of the statement. Just simply do `SDL_Surface * menu = IMG_Load(".\\sprites\\menu\\background.png");`

Comment: Sorry for that, it was because I was trying something and it kept error'ing and when I found out about the true error I forgot to fix that thing, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at documentation maybe you should try using `SDL_BlitScaled` instead of `SDL_BlitSurface`